# C# conversion issue from a generic value to string

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, scientific-notation

I am facing quite an odd issue,....

I have got a code which reads XML and converts each value irrespective of what type it is for example, int, float, double or a String it self to a String value and then stores it into a String variable.

```
String column = System.Convert.ToString(values.GetValue(rowNum, colNum))
```

problem I have is, lets say if "values.GetValue(rowNum, colNum)" returns 0.000003825, then when ran, the value that gets converted and stored in "column" is "3.825E-06" which is in scientific notation which I do not really want,

I want "column" to store value 0.000003825 in string format, how do I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have fixed this now..

It works a treat irrespective of what the type of value we pass through obj,

thanks.

```
        Object obj = -0.00002357467;
        String value = obj.ToString();
        String type = obj.GetType().ToString();

        if (type.Equals("System.Double")&&value.Contains("E-"))
        {
            double doubleValue = (double)obj;
            value = doubleValue.ToString("0.############################"); //thanks @Matthew Watson
        }

        Console.WriteLine(value);   //prints -0.00002357467
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to supply formatting information. Unfortunately, you can't supply formatting information to `System.Convert.ToString()`. Instead, you must call `string.Format()` or `object.ToString()`.

For example:

```
double value = 0.000003825;

string s1 = value.ToString("0.################");
Console.WriteLine(s1);

string s2 = string.Format("{0:0.################}", value);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Comment: "double value = 0.000003825;" in your example, "value" is double but in my case it is generic.

Comment: @SyedSirajUddin By "generic" do you mean "object"? Your problem is that you can't specify a format for an object. You will at some point need to know what type it is in order to provide formatting for it. If you can't do that, you won't be able to set the formatting.

Comment: yes, I mean object, thanks realize that....but still looking to see if there is any better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try ToString() to convert it to object

Comment: You mean convert it to string :)

Comment: Calling ToString() or Convert.ToString() both return the format he doesn't want.